# symfony 500 errors on missing images

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, symfony1, jpeg

We have noticed a number of 500 errors when an image is missing from our site (this happens for various reasons) - symfony will try to locate the asset first of all in the usual 'uploads/custom/myasset.jpg' folder and if it cannot find the asset then it will look through symfony to try find a matching route, its this 'going through' symfony that is causing a slight performance issue and I was wondering if anyone else has encountered this issue and how they resolved it.

I have tried with a mod_rewrite rule but my regexp knowledge sucks!

Cheers!

Comment: If you want to use mod_rewrite to solve this issue, could you please add more details about what should be redirected where, and what you have tried already?

Answer (score 3):

You could add a RewriteCond to exclude a certain directory from the RewriteRule.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Would exclude any request starting with "/images/" from the default rewrite rule for the symfony front controller. You can add as many RewriteCond before the RewriteRule as you want, or you could modify the regexp to account for different cases, like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(images|uploads)/
```

However, your question suggests there is another problem still, as symfony should be throwing 404 expections when it cannot route a request, which results in a HTTP 404 response. It definitely would not result in a HTTP 500 response. Maybe a faulty 404 controller is throwing an exception. You should further investigate the reason of the the error 500.